# <span> line height styling change messing with browser highlighting

Tags: css, highlight, line-breaks

in a  tag I'm changing the line-height:

```
<span class="text-header-huge" style="line-height: 90%;">
    XXX
    <br>
    XXX.
</span>
```

It looks fine, however when I highlight the text with my browser, this happens
[image]

The highlight should fully encase the text.
How do I fix this?

Comment: This is usually the result of your webfont. What webfont are you using? Does the problem exist if you remove the `line-height`?

Comment: @Robotnicka I am using the web font [Titillium Web](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Titillium+Web)

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/855u2qyx/2/) of the problem

Comment: @zgood Thank you for making that, I'll be sure to do that next time

Comment: That's a very good question and I'm not sure if it is possible with the line-height you want. It basically gets chopped off from the text above it. The Mozilla Dev Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection covers what can be affected by the selection pseudo-class: color, background-color, cursor, outline, text-decoration, text-emphasis-color and text-shadow.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's an easy possible solution to this, because the browsers looks to set the *selection's height* according to the font size ... or that's just me being silly (I'm not a guru in these things).

Though if you divide your text into a bunch of `inline-block`'s, you can have something more or less selectable. My version is not perfect, but at least it highlights the entire row. Hope it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/6ue441kz/69/

```css
.text-header-huge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120px; 
  line-height: 80%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.text-header-huge span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-header-huge">
  <span>
    XXX
  </span>
  <br>
  <span>
    XXX
  </span>
  <br>
  <span>
    XXX
  </span>
</div>
```